# Auto resize std::vector when I use insert

Tags: c++, vector

What is elegant way to insert an element to particular position of std::vector ?
If std::vector has size less than a position.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vec(8);
    vec.insert(vec.begin() + 200, 5); // fail, I need auto-resize
}
```

Comment: Well there is `std::vector::resize`.

Comment: @DimChtz, Do I need to check position and size of std::vector and call resize() function every time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::vector::resize`, with appropriate argument. Say you have your:

```
std::vector<int> vec(8);
```

Simply use:

```
vec.resize(201);
vec.insert(vec.begin() + 200, 5);
```

You could also wrap it around your own template function, which could check for possibly needed allocation:

```
template<class T>
void safe_insert(std::vector<T>& vec, const size_t pos, const T arg)
{
    if(vec.size() <= pos) vec.resize(pos);
    vec.insert(vec.begin() + pos, arg);
}
```

Calling it like so:

```
std::vector<int> vec(8);
safe_insert(vec, 200, 5);
std::cout << vec[200];
```

The code outputs: **5**.

Comment: Consider not doing the `+1`. It's OK to insert to the end of a vector (which is the same as appending)

Comment: @M.M thank you - I somehow lost that fact when writing the answer. It has been corrected